# Using 12.0v 2.0A charger on 7.2v 1.5Ah No Li-Ion Drill

Tags: battery-charging

Someone lost the charger, I have a 12.0v 2.0A charger on 7.2v 1.5Ah No Li-Ion Drill

What are the risks? Thanks

[image: Specs for drill battery to be charged]

[image: charger I want to use]

Comment: On top of what Elliot said, the second one isn’t a charger, but an adaptor.

Comment: The specifications printed on the drill are of the battery pack - note for example that the units are Ampere Hours not Amperes. **They do not indicate how to charge it**.  It's unclear if the charge controller must be external, or if DC power should be applied to an internal charge controller.  Without knowing this, there is nothing you can safely do other than cease using it or obtain a matching charger or charging power supply from Ikea.  This is an off topic question about the *usage* of consumer electronics, not an on-topic question about their design supported by necessary details.

Answer (score 4):

The risks are fire and explosion, and these are pretty likely to occur if you connect a 12V charger to a 7.2V LiIon battery.

Use a charger that is designed specifically for the battery you have.

Comment: OP doesn't even have a **charger**, just a 12v power supply which will just pour current into the battery until it catches fire.

Comment: Just to be abundantly clear, what Elliot is saying here is **_DO NOT DO THIS_**.